# How to have a constant in feature scenarios in Behave

Tags: python-behave

Is there a way to set a global variable/constant in `.feature` files in Behave?

For an analytical service, I have many scenarios like this one

```
Scenario: Some scenario
  Given do some action
  And wait for 90 seconds while the action results are ready
  Then verifying some result
```

And recently the requirements has updated and the service can wait for a longer time. This requirement may be changed in future. Is there a way not to find and replace all the "wait for 90 seconds" but have some constant in a feature file that I can update in one place?

My current approach is to refactor the step into `wait for a reasonable time while the action results are ready` and set the constant of *reasonable time* in Python. But in this approach, it's not clear from the tests logs what is the reasonable time for a specific run.

Comment: I do the same thing you are doing (set the constant in the step file). I agree with you that this approach isn't particularly clear when reviewing the feature file and/or logs, but I don't believe behave has built in a way to do what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting a constant amount of time is bad practice

Correct scenario defininition should be:

```
Scenario: Some scenario
  Given do some action
  And wait for the action results are ready
  Then verifying some result
```

In the step implementation of "wait for the action results are ready" an active wait must be made that will end when results are ready